# Scala SBT set dockerRepository "Repository for publishing is not specified"

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I'm trying to publish a scala build to a docker registry with the following command :

```
./sbt "; set dockerRepository := Some(\"registryname/project\"); docker:publish"
```

I am specifying the dockerRepository but when running the command it is throwing the following error :

```
[error] You cannot push a "root" repository. Please rename your repository to <user>/<repo> (ex: <user>/example)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Repository for publishing is not specified.
[error] (all/*:publishConfiguration) Repository for publishing is not specified.
[error] (server/docker:publish) Nonzero exit value: 1
[error] (config/*:publishConfiguration) Repository for publishing is not specified.
[error] Total time: 63 s, completed 01/09/2015 10:48:04 AM
```

When I look at my local docker registry I can see it compiled the docker image but did not prefix the docker registry name :

```
docker images

REPOSITORY                                     TAG                                           IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
example                                        0.0.1    SNAPSHOT   a6eb8942aa9f        8 minutes ago       1.136 GB
```

So it doesn't appear to be accepting the dockerRepository variable I am setting on the command, this is also in the build log :

```
[15:32:58][Step 4/5] [info] Loading project definition from /build/project
[15:33:01][Step 4/5] [info] Set current project to example (in build file:/build/)
[15:33:06][Step 4/5] [info] Defining {.}/*:dockerRepository
[15:33:06][Step 4/5] [info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
[15:33:06][Step 4/5] [info] Reapplying settings...
```

Comment: Did you get it figured out?

Comment: It came down to variable scope try :

./sbt "; set dockerRepository in ThisBuild := Some(\"registryname/project\"); docker:publish"

Answer (score 2):

From the comment of Alex Laverty:

In `build.sbt`:

`dockerRepository in ThisBuild := Some("docker.io")`

or in a project with submodules:

```
lazy val server = (project in file("server"))
  .settings(dockerRepository := Some("docker.io"),
            dockerUsername := Some("pame"),
            ...)
```

Then:

`sbt docker:publish`